# What is the best way find specific pattern using regex?

Tags: regex

I need find a word, that start with alphabetic symbol a-zA-Z and then can be continued by alphabetic symbols\digits, unlimited times

Example:
foo123
f3
3foo - ERROR
asd1
asd

using ECMAScript syntax.
Example on this site can be useful: https://regex101.com/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Reference - What does this regex mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22937618/reference-what-does-this-regex-mean)

Comment: ^[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9]+$

Answer (score 0):

`^[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9]+$`

**Explanation**

`^$` - from start to end (match the whole line)

`[a-zA-Z]` Any letter once

`[a-zA-Z0-9]+` Any letter or any number 1 or more times.